# SVN Notifier for linux?

Tags: linux, svn, notifications

I would like to know if there is any version of this software for linux or any equivalent:
[svn notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/)

Comment: Something like [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html) would be great to have also on linux. I don't know if s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anything (SVN Notifier is a new one on me, but I see the usefulness of it), but using the [SVN::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.67/lib/SVN/Notify.pm) Perl module combined with something like [libnotify](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Gtk2-Notify-0.05/lib/Gtk2/Notify.pm) shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: SVN::Notify is a library to help you push notifications. What the OP is searching for is something to pull them.

Comment: The same result could still be achieved by pushing rather than polling.

Comment: Of course, but maybe he has no control at all over that repository?

Answer (score 1):

The svn-specific tool isn't necessary on Linux, because linux has more general tools that do this easily.  See incron, for instance, which uses inotify.  You should be able to set this up to monitor any file and run commands (svn or otherwise) when changes occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try specto (Its a general notifier written in python) 
It works with SVN, RSS, Email, etc...

http://specto.sourceforge.net/

It is far better than SVN Notifier for me because it is general ;)

Answer (score 0):

Searching around I find [**SVN::Notify**](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/SVN-Notify-29691.shtml) that looks pretty similar.

Comment: SVN::Notify is a library to help you push notifications. What the OP is searching for is something to pull them.